# Angular 4 ng2-bootstrap-modal error: Module parse failed,Unexpected token

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-webpack-starter

I'm trying to deploy an angular 4 + webpack app and got this error on build

```
 ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/ng2-bootstrap-modal/dist/dialog-wrapper.component.ngfactory.ts
    Module parse failed: D:\myapp\$$_gendir\node_modules\ng2-bootstrap-modal\dist\dialog-wrapper.component.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (12:35)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import * as i1 from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal/dist/dialog-wrapper.component';
    | import * as i2 from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal/dist/dialog.service';
    | const styles_DialogWrapperComponent:any[] = ([] as any[]);
    | export const RenderType_DialogWrapperComponent:i0.RendererType2 = i0.╔╡crt({encapsulation:2,
    |     styles:styles_DialogWrapperComponent,data:{}});
     @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory.ts 11:0-114
     @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem there is a fix removing  `include: /ClientApp/` from webpack.config.js. details here:  https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1168